Can I have an empty default LWC property with @wire?
In my LWC component, I have a property for the user without a default value:
<property name="type" type="String" label="Account Type"/>

I want the user to be able to leave this empty most of the time - but if they want, they can use this as an additional filter for a query.
@wire(fetchAccounts, { recordId: '$recordId', type: '$type' })

The problem is with the wiring - as the default is undefined it will not be triggered when the value is empty. But there's no problem when I give type a value.
What are possible options to solve this? I know I could use a picklist or a different default that will be interpreted as null - but I kinda feel like just leaving it blank is most intuitive. Blank = no additional filter.
Or maybe I'm just missing something here that I overlooked. :)

Assigning a default of null should enable this to function. Is that such a bad thing?

@PhilW I think they think that they have to put it in the targetConfig/property somehow, rather than being able to put it in the JS source.

Precisely. Since you can also set a default there, I somehow just assumed that.

Even though @api properties are mostly read-only, there's one exception. You can assign a default value in your LWC, as follows:
@api type = null;

This will allow the wire method to be called without type being populated.

I had no idea! Somehow I expected this to be a part of the property! Thanks!
